# How to describe three different levels of sharing?

Tags: copywriting

A person has some content that they've created, and they want to share it.  The application allows one of 3 states for content.

**Not shared** - Not shared with anyone.  **Open sharing** - shared with everyone.  **Closed sharing** - shared with only those people who you allow access.

What are some better ways of describing / naming these forms of sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ uses "Limited" for limited sharing, which I find works quite well

Answer (score 5):

I would go with Personal / Shared / Public.

Or you could have the phrase "shared with [ me / friends / everyone]." Depending on the context, "friends" could be something more descriptive, like "employees," "my team," or "registered users."

If "closed sharing" means the user is required to specify who has access every time (it's not always the same group) then you might want to go a different direction: Make the item private by default, let the user select people with whom they'd like to share it, and make "everyone" an option.

Answer (score 2):

- Private - not shared
- Public - shared with everyone
- Review - shared with only those people who you allow access.

I'm not crazy about using "review", but it's the only common word I can think of that seems to fit.

Comment: Google+ uses "Limited" for limited sharing, which I find works quite well

Comment: @Rahul: Nice suggestion

Comment: Restricted is another term that is used for sharing with a specific set of named individuals.

Comment: I would say Limited or Restricted rather than Review but Private and Public are easy enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses "custom" which seems to work well.